# AngularJS: Restangular - How to remove query param from URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I setup API base url in Main.js with query param "advertiserId". I would like to remove the query param `advertiserId` in Demo.js. Note I don't want to use `$location` search params (since these are search params from current window URL not the URL I constructed).

Main.js:

```
  Restangular.setBaseUrl("localhost:9000/advertisers");
  Restangular.setDefaultRequestParams({
    "advertiserId": advertiserID
  });
```

Demo.js

```
 Restangular.RemoveRequestParams({
    "advertiserId": advertiserID
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you also just reset the defaults to an empty object in Demo.js?

```
Restangular.SetDefaultRequestParams({});
```

I'm guessing that the Restangular you're using in Demo.js is a newly created instance from the Restangular Service?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse any url with this:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

EDIT:
To remove everything after (and including) the `?` you can use this:

```
url.split("?")[0];
```

Comment: Thanks Michelem. Is there any way to remove parser.search from the URL?